# Proof that positive definite matrix can be factored as $A = VV^{\top}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix. I am trying to prove that there are $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ such that $A_{ij} = v_i^{\top}v_j$.

From the Spectral Theorem, we know that $A$ can be factored as $A = V\Lambda V^T = V^T \Lambda V$, where $V$ is a diagonal matrix whose columns are the unit eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal. This gives the desired result immediately, with the exception that $\Lambda$ must the identity matrix, so $A$ must have eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $n$, which of course is not true in general.

I'm looking for a way to extend this idea to cover the general case, but cannot figure out a way to break up $\Lambda$ to give the desired result.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $A$ can be orthogonally diagonalized as $A = U\Lambda U^T$, then set
$V = U \sqrt{\Lambda}$. Now, what could I mean by $\sqrt{\Lambda}$?

Alternatively, if you know about positive semidefinite square roots, it certainly suffices to set $V = \sqrt A = U\sqrt{\Lambda}U^T$.